# Is there any difference between the terms line of code and statement?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between the terms 'line of code' and 'statement' in programming languages?

Comment: Yes, of course there is, a statement can span multiple lines of code, or one line of code can have multiple statements

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code presumably refers to lines of content in a source file, i.e. the number of lines in a file.  On the other hand, a given statement of code can, and often does, exceed a single line.  For example, consider the following Java statement from the [Javadoc for streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
int sum = widgets.stream()
                 .filter(b -> b.getColor() == RED)
                 .mapToInt(b -> b.getWeight())
                 .sum();
```

One statement spans four physical lines in the editor.  However, we could inline the whole thing into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check following:

```
int a =0;
while(a<100)
{
    cout<<
          "Is it ok"<<
          a <<
          "is the current value of 'a'"<<endl;
    a++;
}
```

Above code snippet is having:

Line of code: 9

Simple Statements: 3

Compound Statements: 1

Answer (score 0):

Line of code is basically how many end points you are using. A Statement is the group of code that you produce to create an expected output.

For example in a conditional statement using if else, you can right that in multiple line of core or using only one line via Ternary method.

Sample:

```
if($var == 0) {
    echo "this is zero";
} else {
    echo "not a zero";
}
```

that basically created 5 line of code. In ternary you can go like this

```
$var == 0 ? echo "this is zero" : echo "not a zero";
```

As you see the result is the same only it is created in 1 line of code.
Hope this helps you moving forward